# C++11: bind std::sort for user-defined type and then use that bind as an argument in ctor

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

**This is complicated**. I wanted to create a class than can hold a sorting algorithm (mostly to compare how they work). Array that is to be sorted will be of type: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>`. I am going to use different functions to sort it, I have tested `std::sort()` with a function looking like `bool compare_func(std::shared_ptr<Item> const& a, std::shared_ptr<Item> const& b)` and it worked correctly

The algorithm class also contains other data, for example name (std::string) and amount (int) of items to be sorted

The problem begins when I want to create and put an object of type algorithm into `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Algorithm>>`

I have already found on SO that std::bind is not an object, so first I need to create something like this:

```
struct std_sort {
    template <typename RndIt, typename Cmp>
    void operator()(RndIt begin, RndIt end, Cmp cmp) {
        std::sort(begin, end, cmp);
    }
};
```

The problem begins when I try to add an object of type algorithm

```
vect.push_back(std::make_shared<Algorithm>(std::string("std::sort()"), zero, zero, amount,
        std::bind
        (
            static_cast<void(*)
            (
                std::shared_ptr<Item> a,
                std::shared_ptr<Item> b,
                std::function
                <bool(
                        std::shared_ptr<Item> const& c, std::shared_ptr<Item> const& d
                )>
            )>
            (std_sort()), //error on this line
            std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3
        )
    ));
```

The plan was to call this vector's algorithms to sort a gievn array, It would look like `vect[0](array.begin(), array.end(), compare_func);`

Everything goes well except for the last argument, the expected argument is of this type:

```
typedef std::function
    <void(
            std::shared_ptr<Item> a,
            std::shared_ptr<Item> b,
            std::function
            <bool(
                std::shared_ptr<Item> const& c, std::shared_ptr<Item> const& d
            )>
    )>
    sorting_function;
```

The error I get (from MinGW)

```
error: invalid static_cast from type 'std_sort' to type 'void (*)(std::shared_ptr<Item>, std::shared_ptr<Item>, std::function<bool(const std::shared_ptr<Item>&, const std::shared_ptr<Item>&)>)'
```

If I remove static_cast I get tons of typical template errors

Comment: You've marked the question as both c++ and c++11, do you mean to say that c++14 is allowed?  If so, this becomes a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks for C++14 answer, but Is it even possible to do in C++11?

Comment: The answer does compile with c++11, see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c822ec41ff40ba5

Comment: Much Thanks. I will look It later, I have no time now but I guess I will underdstand everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this call:

```
vect[0](array.begin(), array.end(), compare_func);
```

Is giving *iterators* to `vect[0]`, but expecting an actual instance.  You should change the type of your `sorting_function` to:

```
typedef std::function
    <void(
            std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>::iterator a,
            std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>::iterator b,
            std::function
            <bool(
                std::shared_ptr<Item> const& c, std::shared_ptr<Item> const& d
            )>
    )>
    sorting_function;
```

Second, you can't bind to the struct directly, because it isn't a function.  `std_sort::operator()`, however, *is* a function.  But since it's a template, it gets a bit more complicated to set up:

```
std_sort inst();
auto fn = std::bind(
    &std_sort::operator()<const std::shared_ptr<Item>&,
                          std::less<std::shared_ptr<Item>>>,
    &inst, _1, _2);
```

Although, it seems you'd be better off creating an instance of `std::function` directly, and then binding to that.

```
sorting_function fn(std_sort());
vect.push_back(std::make_shared<Algorithm>(..., std::bind(fn, ...)));
```

Or even better, just use lambdas:

```
vect.push_back(std::make_shared<Algorithm>(...,
    [](std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>::iterator first,
       std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>::iterator last,
       std::function
            <bool(
                std::shared_ptr<Item> const& c, std::shared_ptr<Item> const& d
            )> compare_func) {
        std_sort()(first, last, compare_func);
    }));
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c750683551be174)

Comment: Changed the typedef and static_cast. I get now: `invalid static_cast from type 'std_sort' to type 'void (*)(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item> >::iterator, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item> >::iterator, std::function<bool(const std::shared_ptr<Item>&, const std::shared_ptr<Item>&)>) {aka void (*)(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Item>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Item>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item> > >, std::function<bool(const std::shared_ptr<Item>&, const std::shared_ptr<Item>&)>)}`

Comment: @Xeverous I don't think a `static_cast` is possible in this context.  If you create the function before passing it to `std::bind`, however, it should work fine.

Comment: Now I get `no known conversion for argument 5 from 'std::_Bind<std::function<void(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Item>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Item>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item> > >, std::function<bool(const std::shared_ptr<Item>&, const std::shared_ptr<Item>&)>)> (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>))(std_sort (*)())>' to 'sorting_function'`

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: This time `no known conversion for argument 5 from '[...]' to 'sorting_function'`. But the error points to the line `&inst, _1, _2);`

Comment: Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me?  I can take a better look there.

Comment: http://ideone.com/cFy3Rt It compiles if I dont invoke the function. I think that something is wrong with compare function signature

Comment: @Xeverous You're accessing your arguments incorrectly, I've updated the answer with a compiling sample.

Comment: I've checked your solution. Apparently the only thing I was doing wrong was `vect[0](v.begin(), v.end(), Compare);` because vect is a vector of shared Algorithms, not functions. When I saw the arrow in `vect[0]->func(v.begin(), v.end(), Compare);` I realized everything, also why I had such compiler errors